# Python game save file

Tags: python, file, save

I'm writing a game in Python and have come to the point where I need a way of saving the players progress. I was thinking of having the script create a text file and write a couple of lines (for storing stat variables, and the room number) when the player exits the game. But I also need it to check if that file exits on startup and, if so, apply the stored values to the corresponding variables. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

Two different issues here:

1. What to store in the file and how to store it
2. The logic of when to store and when to load

The first issue is simpler to address as it's more generic. You have several good options here: one is using Python's `ConfigParser` class for Windows `.ini` - like configuration files. Alternatively you can use `pickle` to simply dump some sort of a configuration/settings data structure (may be a nested dict). Then there's the built-in SQLite binding. There are other options - it all depends on the level of complexity you want.

The second issue is more specific to your application. You can try to open the config file on startup and if it's there, read its contents. Later, you can periodically store the settings/progress into it. A word of advice: keep the *complete* set of settings in a consistent data structure at all times - even if only part of the settings are in the config file when you're reading it (for some reason), have default values for your settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
if os.path.exists('yourplayerfile'):
   with open('yourplayerfile') as f:
        # work with f
with open('yourplayerfile','a') as f:
     # update f
```

That's the outline you have to work with.

Comment: Don't you think checking whether the file exists is somewhat unnecessary? After all, `a` will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: A A - I thought the OP asked he wanted to check for the file during the startup. I should have made it as part of if stmt, editing it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you save in sqlite or some things like this ... but i can't understand where is your question? saving file or read file?

```
try:
   f=open('/tmp/workfile', 'w')
   # i find file 
except:
   #there is no file
<open file '/tmp/workfile', mode 'w' at 80a0960>
```

...
read docs http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/tut/node9.html

Comment: No, please use `with open(file) as f` instead. It's much more cleaner.

Comment: What it needs to do is create a file to store variables that determine players progress, it also needs to check on startup if that file already exits,  and if so apply the data inside to the player progress varibles

Comment: try check your file and if dosent exist execute except