# Python game - creating a save file?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, python-2.7, save

I'm creating a game in python 2.7.2, but I've hit a snag. I would like to save the game's state in the game by having the program create a python script and inside there being a module 
basically saying to jump to such and such module in the game.

It's an entirely console based hacking game, based on real techniques and programs. 
And it's set in an linux enviroment ;)

I did find this :

[Python game save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799526/python-game-save-file)

but some of the bits of code I'm not sure how to use and I'm not sure they would fit my scenario perfectly.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Kimvais said, using the pickle module is an easy option.  I use it for my game to save and load profile data, and to save and load each level.  Here's an example of a function that save's a player's  profile which includes the levels she's unlocked, items collected etc.

```
def writeProfile(profileName, profileData):
    """ pickle user profile data """

    os.chdir(PROFILE_DIR)

    fileName = profileName + ".dat"
    f = open(fileName, "wb")
    pickle.dump(profileData, f)
    f.close()

    os.chdir("..")
```

profileName is a string with the name of a .dat file where player data is stored.  profileData is the new data (stored in python objects like tuples, lists and dictionaries) that will overwrite the old data and be stored in the .dat file.  PROFILE_DIR is a path to the directory where the saved game data should be stored.  os is a python module that does stuff like navigating directories and finding files.

Comment: thanks, I've moved to processing.org now, but should I need to use python again (which I probably will) this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some internal object in the game, such as "board" or "player" or similar, that holds the game state.

If you don't need cross-platform compatibility or such, the easiest way to store python objects is via [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

If your game state is in dictionaries, lists and such and need a more platform-agnostic file format, you could store them in [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Of course, both formats are *very* easily reverse-engineered and hacked - so you might consider some sort of encryption/hmac - of course if you ship your game as source code then there is always easier ways to hack your game than modifying savefiles.

Comment: I was thinking more about having the program generate a script, that tells it to import the main game module and then jump to such and such module(level) in the game. - how would I go about creating this?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do it that way?

Comment: well, python _doesn't store variables permanently_ does it? and I need it _cross platform_. I store all my levels and data in modules so IMO, it would be easier to create a python script that re-directs it to a module.

Comment: pickle can be used to store _any_ serializable object e.g. a variable.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to have some sample code of the _modules_ you want to save that you are talking about?

Comment: pickle isn't cross platform and yes, I will soon :)